# Differences between CMS and RDBMS

Tags: database, content-management-system

I was actually reading up on CMS systems like Drupal, and noticed that they're similar to RDBMSes. I was wondering what the differences might be between them. When would we use an RDBMS and when would we use a CMS? Kinda confused and appreciate any input on this. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how they are related. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I do have to say, after looking at this Wikipedia article, I can see where you'd be confused.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not similar at all. A CMS is a Content management System - it's used for maintaining content in a website.  In a CMS you generally think of content as "pages" or "documents"

An RDBMS is a Relational Database Management System.  An RDBMS manages data - in the form of text, numbers, etc, in a highly relational format.  In an RDBMS, you think of data as "numeric values", strings of "text", "datetimes", or other primitive data formats.

Usually a CMS uses an RDBMS under the hood to store the data, which the CMS displays as page content.

Comment: thanks david. might i ask- how, where and in what format are "pages" and "documents" stored in a CMS?

Comment: @Ockhams As files on a web-server. You usually want to use a CMS to hold your JavaScript and CSS files, and images.

Comment: It depends on the CMS in question, but in the majority of CMS's I've worked with, the content (the text) for the "Pages" in a Content Management System are acttually stored in text fields in a Database (RDBMS).  There are exceptions, of course.  Some use a non-relational database such as MongoDB.  The page content is usually in the DB, but things like the page template, css, etc MAY be stored in a DB or they MAY be stored in files on the web server.  There are many implementations of how to build a CMS.

Answer (score 10):

You are asking what is the difference between a *car* and a *Diesel engine*.

**[CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system)** (*Content management system*) is a full-blown system allowing end-users to view and modify content (articles, media, etc.) in an easy way. See: [List of content management systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems).

**[RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system)** (*Relational database management system*) is a back-end software used to store low-level data. Typically CMSes use RDBMSes (like MySQL), but this is not a requirement. Nowadays end-users seldom use RDBMS directly.

Answer (score 3):

After researching this topic (and being a Senior Oracle DBA and Java Developer) and reaching a good understanding of both, I can answer this.

Think of a CMS like Amazon, they host digital content such as books, movies and a myriad of other merchandise.  Amazon has a fairly open ended query capability that helps you find products quickly and accurately (most times anyway!).

Now imagine this, Amazon goes in and organizes content a little different for logic/efficiency sakes, so what happens to the applications that use it...typically nothing!

You have to create a schema in an RDBMS and write code to interact with that schema.  A CMS has facilities to store, organize and retrieve content (although some software would have to be developed that uses/interfaces with the "system").  Arguably, one could create database tables that have blob/clob types and make something CMS like.

One fine difference is that a CMS can support MIME types such as PDF and .DOCX files and understand how to search those for content as well (unlike a BLOB, it's just a BLOB right?).

I wouldn't limit a CMS as saying it is a "document repository" for web-based applications, because it is much more than that; a CMS can store structured, semi-structured and completely unstructured data (executables/.bin files/imagery...whatever!)

Comment: I like David's answer but this is definitely more thorough.

Answer (score 1):

They are really not the same:

RDBMS : Relational Database Management System - for handling data (SQL, MYSQL)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system

CMS: Content Management System - For working with web site content
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the point here...As far as i know a CMS uses an RDBMS to provided its data. As far as i know a CMS is just an abstraction layer built upon a database. It's much easier for a user to edit content by using the cms, then by directly editing data in a database table.

Answer (score 0):

A CMS, strictly speaking, is a Content Management System, typically used for serving up web pages (SharePoint and other document repositories not withstanding). An RDBMS is a Relational Database Management System. CMSs usually reside within an RDBMS. RDBMSs are also typically used for much more intensive purposes than a CMS, for example, storing customer information or product data.

Answer (score 0):

So one can integrate code e.g. java ... in a CMS to interact with a RDBMS e.g. MySql to endup with a CRUD (Create , Read, Update, Delete) web type application ?

The idea behind this, is to allow any user of the web site to update (specifically allowed) data stored in the RDBMS.

We seem to be getting close to an eCommerce website ...

CMS+RDBMS+code = eCommerce website

Not sure if that exists though ?